# Find scalar such that $B$ is a basis for $\mathbf R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{v_1=(1,1,-1), v_2=(-1,3,1),v_3=(a,2-a,a+1)\} \subseteq \mathbf R^3$. Find the scalar $a$ such that $B$ is a basis for $\mathbf R^3$.
I tried taking a vector $(x,y,z) = α_1v_1 + α_2v_2 + α_3v_3$ but I got stuck in a point when I tried solving the system but I got $2a+1 = (x+z)/c$. Should I try a different approach?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Try to use LaTeX on your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The determinant
$$\det(v_1,v_2,v_3)= \begin{vmatrix}1&-1&a \\ 1&3&2-a \\ -1&1& a+1\end{vmatrix} \ne 0 $$.

Comment: So a != 0? Also is there a similar way in which I could find a if the task asked for B to be linearly dependent/independent?

Comment: The simplest criterion is the determinant: linear dependence/independence is equivalent to zero/non-zero determinant. You should find $a=/\ne -\dfrac12$.